# SQL: Update column with with an index that resets if column changes

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase

Firstly, sorry for the wording of the question. I'm not too sure how to express it. Hopefully the example below is clear.

If I have a table

```
Id | Type | Order
0  | Test | null
1  | Test | null
2  | Blah | null
3  | Blah | null
```

I want to turn it into this

```
Id | Type | Order
0  | Test | 1
1  | Test | 2
2  | Blah | 1
3  | Blah | 2
```

So I'm grouping the table by 'type' and allocating a number to 'order' incrementally. It'll start at 1 per type.

How should I go about doing it?

Db I'm using is Sybase 15.

Comment: My answer assumes SQL Server.  What is your RDBMS?  Please specify.

Comment: I'm using Sybase, whilst I'm sure your answer is correct I can't seem to get the same results in Sybase.

Comment: I have deleted my answer and added the `sybase` tag so others know your RDBMS.

Comment: I think you should still keep your answer just as a reference.

Comment: What's not working with [Shark's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8513859/132382)?  Does Sybase (ASE?  SQL Anywhere?) 15 not implement ROW_NUMBER?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    Id, 
    Type, 
    row_number() over(partition by Type order by Id) as [Order]
from YourTable
```

You should utilize the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to get you what you're looking for.

> **ROW_NUMBER** (Transact-SQL)
>
> Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result
> set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

Comment: Whilst this doesn't solve my exact issue. It is the correct way of solving it in the general case.